# How to add Dart FileHeader with Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

I am trying to add file header in android studio with dart,
able to add in java but not in the dart file. this is what i have done

[image: for Dartfile]

[image: for java]

Comment: Try this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59084916/14952004

Comment: Like this ?   
///
// @ Author: yourName
// @ Date: ${DATE}
///
@ctrl_aziz

Answer (score 0):

From Android studio settings.

[image: android studio settings]

Go to Editor -> File and code templates -> File -> Dart File.

Then past this command there like in the photo and change your name.

[image]

Comment: #set( $USER ="Mohit.Jadav" )
/**
 * Created by ${USER} on ${DATE}
 */

Still not working in dart file